# CSOM: Get the exact Url of SharePoint hosted list

Tags: javascript, csom, sharepoint-hosted-app

here I wish to retrieve the URL of SharePoint hosted list
it's like

```
http://app-0329d4c1001648.spapps.com/sites/site1/EmployeeList/EmpList
```

I tried some approaches but these are not that much useful,with them I can fetch list which is not hosted.
the code I am using

```
var hostWebUrl;
var appWebUrl;
var appCtxSite;
hostWebUrl = decodeURIComponent(manageQueryStringParameter('SPHostUrl'));
appWebUrl = decodeURIComponent(manageQueryStringParameter('SPAppWebUrl'));

function manageQueryStringParameter(paramToRetrieve) {
    var params =
    document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");
    var strParams = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
        var singleParam = params[i].split("=");
        if (singleParam[0] == paramToRetrieve) {
            return singleParam[1];
        }
    }
}
$(document).ready(function () {   
    var scriptbase = hostWebUrl + "/_layouts/15/";
    $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.RequestExecutor.js");    
    $(".View").click(function () {             
        listAllCategories();
    });   
});

function listAllCategories() {

    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(appWebUrl);
    var context = new SP.AppContextSite(ctx, hostWebUrl);
    var web = context.get_web(); //Get the Web 
    var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("EmpList"); //Get the List

    var query = new SP.CamlQuery(); //The Query object. This is used to query for data in the List

    query.set_viewXml('<View><RowLimit></RowLimit>10</View>');

    var items = list.getItems(query);

    ctx.load(list); //Retrieves the properties of a client object from the server.
    ctx.load(items);

    var table = $("#tblcategories");
    //var table1 = $("#tblcategories1");
    var innerHtml = "<tr><td>Title</td><td> First Name</td><td> Last Name</td><td> Designation</td><td> Department</td><td> DOJ</td><td>Id</td></tr>";

    //Execute the Query Asynchronously
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, function () {
            var itemInfo = '';
            var enumerator = items.getEnumerator();
            while (enumerator.moveNext()) {
                var currentListItem = enumerator.get_current();
                innerHtml += "<tr><td>" + currentListItem.get_item('Title') + "</td><td>" + currentListItem.get_item('E_FirstName') + "</td><td>" + currentListItem.get_item('E_LastName') + "</td><td>" + currentListItem.get_item('E_Desig') + "</td><td>" + currentListItem.get_item('E_Dept') + "</td><td>" + currentListItem.get_item('E_DOJO') + "</td><td>" + currentListItem.get_item('E_Id') + "</td></tr>";
            }

            table.html(innerHtml);
            //innerHtml1 = " <Table><tr><td><input type='button' name='back' value='Back' class='back'/></td></tr></Table>";
            //table1.html(innerHtml1);
        }),

        Function.createDelegate(this, fail)
        );

}

function fail() {
    alert("Operation failed  " + arguments[1].get_message());
}
```

but this is not giving me the url of hosted list,how do I achieve that

Comment: Add some code snippet that you have already tried.

Comment: i have added the code to question

Comment: what error ae you getting?

Comment: 404 for list,list not found

Answer (score 0):

[This article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nickpinheiro/2015/01/30/build-a-sharepoint-hosted-app-to-access-list-data-in-your-host-web-using-the-rest-api-in-10-easy-steps/) on Microsoft would be opt one for you.

They mentioned that url:

`appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getbytitle('Posts')/items?`

in their code.

Hope this helps. If this answer your query please do not forget to mark it as answer.

Comment: thanks,but i tried this approach as well but this is didn't worked for me